# The output laser power of fiber amplifier fluctuates up and down with the increase of pump power

Tags: laser, fiber-optics

I was engaged in the research of 2um thulium-doped fiber laser. During the experiment, I found that when the oscillator seed light was injected into the amplifier stage for amplification, the output laser presented a phenomenon of periodic fluctuation and rise. I tried many methods (changing the coil radius of the amplifier stage, adjusting the injected seed light power, changing the active fiber model of the amplifier stage, Optimization of amplifying stage, active size, length, etc.) have not improved this phenomenon, have you ever encountered similar situations? Can you give me some advice? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information? The amplifier is working in continuous or pulsed mode? What is the scheme of the amplifier. What is the pump wavelength? Did you look with a thermal camera? It is difficult to help you with the debugging without these informations.

Comment: The amplifier is working in continuous mode. The scheme of the amplifier is traditional MOPA structure. Pump wavelength is 793 nm, laser wavelength is 1907 nm.

Comment: At one pump power, the output power is stable? Can you quantify the spontaneous emission? Is the pump wavelength stable with pump power? Can you have a look to the setup with a thermal camera?

Comment: The output power is stable at one pump power. The pump wavelength is stable with pump power. I check the setup with a thermal camera and found the output side of CPS is hot when the output laser power is decrease.